# How to show the Options (HTML) with the elements of the Database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to make the elements that are registered in the database appear as options of a 'select' in an Html form

select MYSQL: table 'project' column 'name'

select function and HTML form:

```js
    con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT name FROM project", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="box-form">
    <div class="box-header">
        <p class="title">
            Choose the BOT
        </p>
    </div>
    <form id="form-submit">
        <img alt="robot-icon" class="robot-icon" src="assets / icons / robotic.png" />
        <select id="project" name="project" placeholder="BOT">
            <option value="database-database">select database</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="js/db_select.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this after get result data.

i assume result is an array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="project" name="project" placeholder="BOT">
            <option value="">select database</option>
    </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    result = ['db1','db2','db3']
    for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
      $("#project").append(new Option(result[i],result[i]));
    }

  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you help me get the results in an array?

Comment: sure, are you using nodejs for get data from db?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's an array of objects ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp)).

So I guess that there's an ID, and a name (label).

```js
con.connect(err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    con.query('SELECT name FROM project', (err, res, fields) => {
        res.forEach(project => {
            document.querySelector('#project').innerHTML += `<option value="database-${project.id}">${project.name}</option>`;
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/KaKi87/o6rmbh57/